# Multi Threading in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to create 3 threads.
Each thread will print on the screen a collor and sleep for x seconds.
Thread A will print red; Thread B will print yellow; Thread C will print green;

All threads must wait until its their turn to print.
The first thread to print must be Red, after printing, Red will tell Yellow that's its turn to print and so on.
The threads must be able to print multiple times (user specific)

I'm stuck because calling @firstFlag.signal outside a Thread isn't working and the 3 threads aren't working on the right order
How do I make the red Thread go first?

my code so far:

```
@lock = Mutex.new
@firstFlag = ConditionVariable.new
@secondFlag = ConditionVariable.new
@thirdFlag = ConditionVariable.new

print "Tell me n's vallue:"
@n = gets.to_i

@threads = Array.new

@threads << Thread.new() {
  t = Random.rand(1..3)
  n = 0
  @lock.synchronize {  
    for i in 0...@n do
      @firstFlag.wait(@lock, t)     
      puts "red : #{t}s"
      sleep(t)
      @secondFlag.signal      
    end
  }
}

@threads << Thread.new() {
  t = Random.rand(1..3)
  n = 0
  @lock.synchronize {  
    for i in 0...@n do         
      @secondFlag.wait(@lock, t)     
      puts "yellow : #{t}s"
      sleep(t)
      @thirdFlag.signal
    end
  }
}

@threads << Thread.new() {
  t = Random.rand(1..3)
  n = 0
  @lock.synchronize {  
    for i in 0...@n do      
      @thirdFlag.wait(@lock, t)     
      puts "green : #{t}s"
      sleep(t)
      @firstFlag.signal
    end
  }
}

@threads.each {|t| t.join}
@firstFlag.signal
```

Comment: Hi Diego, and welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear to me what your actual question is (in fact, you haven't _asked_ a question). Can you clarify where exactly you are stuck? Have a look at [ask] for tips on how to write good questions. You can use the [edit] link to add more details to your question.

Comment: I'm stuck because calling @firstFlag.signal outside a Thread isn't working and the 3 threads aren't working on the right order.
How do I make the red Thread go first? ps. sorry, first time asking a question here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three bugs in your code:

**First bug**

Your `wait` calls use a timeout. This means your threads will become de-synchronized from your intended sequence, because the timeout will let each thread slip past your intended wait point.

**Solution**: change all your wait calls to NOT use a timeout:

```
@xxxxFlag.wait(@lock)
```

---

**Second bug**

You put your sequence trigger AFTER your `Thread.join` call in the end. Your `join` call will never return, and hence the last statement in your code will never be executed, and your thread sequence will never start.

**Solution**: change the order to signal the sequence start first, and then join the threads:

```
@firstFlag.signal
@threads.each {|t| t.join}
```

---

**Third bug**

The problem with a `wait/signal` construction is that it does not buffer the signals.
Therefore you have to ensure all threads are in their `wait` state before calling `signal`, otherwise you may encounter a race condition where a thread calls `signal` before another thread has called `wait`.

**Solution**: This a bit harder to solve, although it is possible to solve with `Queue`. But I propose a complete rethinking of your code instead. See below for the full solution.

---

**Better solution**

I think you need to rethink the whole construction, and instead of condition variables just use `Queue` for everything. Now the code becomes much less brittle, and because `Queue` itself is thread safe, you do not need any critical sections any more.

The advantage of `Queue` is that you can use it like a `wait/signal` construction, but it buffers the signals, which makes everything much simpler in this case.

Now we can rewrite the code:

```
redq    = Queue.new
yellowq = Queue.new
greenq  = Queue.new
```

Then each thread becomes like this:

```
@threads << Thread.new() {
  t = Random.rand(1..3)
  n = 0

  for i in 0...@n do
    redq.pop
    puts "red : #{t}s"
    sleep(t)
    yellowq.push(1)
  end
}
```

And finally to kick off the whole sequence:

```
redq.push(1)
@threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked nicely. I'm not sure how Queue's works tho, and how different they are from actual Threads.

Comment: Queue is a data structure. We're still using Threads like before, we're just communicating between them with a Queue instead of signal and wait. Just put "queue ruby" in a Google search, and you can find some decent tutorials and examples if you want to learn more.

Comment: Cool trick with the queues, don't think I've seen that before. But then I don't do a lot of multithreading in Ruby. This a common pattern?

Comment: Good question. I don't write a lot of multithreading either, but from what I have seen Queues are used quite often. In fact signals in my opinion seem extremely error prone, and you probably only want to use them in special circumstances. Any time you have a critical section, mutexes and signals, you really have to think 3x as hard as normal to make sure you know what you are doing. So if a problem can be resolved without needing to think 3x as hard as normal, then I prefer that solution :) Queues are nice because they take care of all the tricky thread safety for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd redesign this slightly. Think of your `ConditionVariable`s as flags that a thread uses to say it's done for now, and name them accordingly:

```
@lock = Mutex.new
@thread_a_done = ConditionVariable.new
@thread_b_done = ConditionVariable.new
@thread_c_done = ConditionVariable.new
```

Now, thread A signals it's done by doing `@thread_a_done.signal`, and thread B can wait for that signal, etc. Thread A of course needs to wait until thread C is done, so we get this kind of structure:

```
 @threads << Thread.new() {
  t = Random.rand(1..3)
  @lock.synchronize {
    for i in 0...@n do
      @thread_c_done.wait(@lock)
      puts "A: red : #{t}s"
      sleep(t)
      @thread_a_done.signal
    end
  }
}
```

A problem here is that you need to make sure that thread A in the first iteration doesn't wait for a flag signal. After all, it's to go first, so it shouldn't wait for anyone else. So modify it to:

```
@thread_c_done.wait(@lock) unless i == 0
```

Finally, once you have created your threads, kick them all off by invoking `run`, then `join` on each thread (so that your program doesn't exit before the last thread is done):

```
@threads.each(&:run)
@threads.each(&:join)
```

Oh btw I'd get rid of the timeouts in your `wait` as well. You have a hard requirement that they go in order. If you make the signal wait time out you screw that up - threads might still "jump the queue" so to speak.

**EDIT** as @casper remarked below, this still has a potential race condition: Thread A could call `signal` *before* thread B is waiting to receive it, in which case thread B will miss it and just wait indefinitely. A possible way to fix this is to use some form of a `CountDownLatch` - a shared object that all threads can wait on, which gets released as soon as all threads have signalled that they're ready. The [ruby-concurrency](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem has an implementation of this, and in fact might have other interesting things to use for more elegant multi-threaded programming.

Sticking with pure ruby though, you could possibly fix this by adding a second `Mutex` that guards shared access to a boolean flag to indicate the thread is ready.

Comment: I think you still have one problem here, and that's a race condition where thread A calls `signal` before thread B has reached `wait`. Basically you have to guarantee that all threads are in their `wait` state before the first `signal` is called, otherwise the whole sequence may never kick off.

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the timeout from the waits as you sugested. And I think I've reached a solution quite similar to what you proposed. Could you take a look at my answer?

Comment: Nice find on ruby-concurrecy. CyclicBarrier looks like it could be used here for the startup synchronization: http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you guys that answered. I've found a solution:

I've created a fourth thread. Because I found out that calling "@firstFlag.signal" outside a thread doesn't work, because ruby has a "main thread" that sleeps when you "run" other threads.
So, "@firstFlag.signal" calling must be inside a thread so it can be on the same level of the CV.wait

I solved the issue using this:

```
@threads << Thread.new {
  sleep 1
  @firstFlag.signal
}
```

This fourth thread will wait for 1 sec before sending the first signal to red. This only sec seems to be enough for the others thread reach the wait point.
And, I've removed the timeout, as you sugested.

//Edit//

I realized I don't need a fourth Thread, I could just make thread C do the first signal.
I made thread C sleep for 1 sec to wait the other two threads enter in wait state, then it signals red to start and goes to wait too

```
@threads << Thread.new() {
  sleep 1
  @redFlag.signal

  t = Random.rand(1..3)
  n = 0
  @lock.synchronize {  
    for i in 0...@n do      
      @greenFlag.wait(@lock)     
      puts "verde : #{t}s"
      sleep(t)
      @redFlag.signal 
      n += 1
    end
  }
}
```

Comment: You should never rely on timing tricks with Threads. Even if you `sleep 1` here it does not guarantee the other threads have reached their `wait` state. What if the CPU is busy doing some other tasks, or the computer is busy swapping memory, then `sleep 1` will not be long enough, and your script will fail. The only proper solution is a solution that does not rely on timing tricks. Remember, your code has to be robust, not brittle. Brittle code can fall apart at any moment, and will produce bugs when you least expect it. Using sleep like this will create brittle code.

Comment: If you still want to use wait/signal, then here is an example of a version that guarantees synchronization without timing tricks: https://gist.github.com/casper/92fe3651a6fa81083f66811e985251ec

Comment: I know I mentioned using a sleep timer in my answer but Casper is right that this is not really reliable.